# Return only first found value from for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I need to find the "value/pair" that is equal to `xbrl:concept": "se:Bank"`. XSLT finds 2 "value/pairs". Since the data extraction is for a single header I need only 1 `heading` answer. In below code I am trying to restrict the `xsl:for-each` by using `[position() = 1]` but still get the return of the 2 index positions.

This example is minimized to fit a proper question. In the real scenario I am producing about 100-130 headings.

Can this be solved with an `for-each` or should I move to another XSLT element?

The code in [xsltfiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA1W/1)

Below you find same code:

**JSON**

```
<data>
{
  "report": {
    "facts": [
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:Bank",
        "numericValue": 1000,
        "heading": "Bank balance"
      },
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:CompanyName",
        "value": "Great Company Ltd"
      },
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:Bank",
        "numericValue": 3000,
        "heading": "Bank balance"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  
  <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->
    
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Printout heading -->
    
    <xsl:template match="//*[@key='facts']">
        
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank'][position() = 1]">
          <xsl:value-of select="../*[@key='heading']"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

`Bank balanceBank balance`

**Wanted result**

`Bank balance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the collection of nodes into a variable, then select the first of them

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@key='facts']">
    <xsl:variable name="headings"  select="//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']/../*[@key='heading']"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$headings[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

[Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA1W/4)

Or even simpler, pass those nodes to `head`

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@key='facts']">
    <xsl:value-of select="head(//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']/../*[@key='heading'])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

[Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA1W/3)

Answer (score 3):

The construct `//*[1]` often causes problems: it parses as `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::*[1]` which selects every descendant that is the first child of its parent. What people usually want here is `(//*)[1]` which selects the first descendant in the entire document.

The problem is obscured here because it appears in the form of the complex expression `//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank'][position() = 1]` but the issue is the same; what you want is `(//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank'])[position() = 1]`, or more concisely `(//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank'])[1]`.

Comment: Not sure if understood the answer correctly. Testing the answers 3 code snippets returns the "xbrl:concept" value, meanwhile the goal was to find all "xbrl:concept" with value "se:CompanyName" and return one result of "heading". When having all 3 SO answers it strikes me that one solution could be to only have the heading in one of the 2 found "xbrl:concept".

Comment: You want the first item in the sequence `//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']`. One way of getting this is to write `(//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank'])[1]` (note the parens). Another way is to write `head(//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank'])`. The way you've done it is incorrect: I tried to explain why.

Comment: I want the first item of key "heading" that is a result of finding all //*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `for-each`, simply select the first element of your sequence with e.g. the `head` function:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@key='facts']">
    
  <xsl:value-of select="head(fn:map[fn:string[@key = 'xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']]/fn:string[@key = 'heading'])"/>
```

Declare `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`, I don't think it makes sense to ignore the names of elements completely and simply select based on the `key` attribute.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion. But since there are 3 keynames with "xbrl:concept", it returns heading of the first keyname which is not "Bank Balance".

Comment: @Toolbox, sorry about that, your original check about the value slipped through my edit, now fixed.